# How should I handle different aspect ratios in a fullscreen game?

Tags: c#

I am creating a game using C#, GDI+ and Raster images (2D images).  For performance sake, I believe that I should have the game change the user's resolution to 800 x 600 and run the game in that setting.  However, the graphics look distorted in a wide screen since the aspect ratio for 800 x 600 is different than from a wide screen.  I cannot figure out how to determine the aspect ratio.

How is game programming normally handled on different resolutions?  Should I even change the user's resolution?  If I dont change the resolution, the game slows down a lot.

Also, some wide screens will "maintain the aspect ratio" when changing the resolution to 800 x 600 (thus creating black bars on the right and left) and some wide screens will fill up the entire screen.  How do people handle that situation??

Comment: Why deal with this performance hit? Any reason you considered and rejected XNA?

Comment: I already got into GDI+ before I heard about XNA.  The game is half way built.  Is XNA that much better?  Is there not perf hit to XNA?  I don't know much about it.  ------ I continued looking around.  I think ppl either use a 800 x 600 aspect ratio if the screen is regular, otherwise they use 1280 x 720 for wide screen.

Comment: Don't forget about 5/4 screens and others. You will need some general solution.

Comment: @CRobinson XNA is hardware accelerated - you should really put some research into it, and it is 10x faster to make something in it compared to GDI+ (once you learn it) - especially for 2D games.

Comment: @CRobinson e.g. I am running at 1920x1080 with (essentially) a 4096x4096 texture with 200 dynamic 2D lights and 1500+ particles at 700FPS on a GTX260. You won't come close to that with GDI+.

Comment: @Jonathan: You could just edit your previous comment to add these infos ;)

Comment: @JonathanDickinson I came from the GDI+ world myself and have since moved to XNA. XNA is way more than 10x more powerful than GDI+, even for 2D stuff, I'd say closer to 100x. CRobinson, I would highly recommend taking the plunge. I found it to be a really simple transition. It took me all of 10 minutes to get a sprite drawing the way I was used to in GDI/GDI+ (not even a hyperbole, ten minutes).

Comment: Why not just add a black border instead of changing the resolution. Movies get away with this all the time.

Answer (score 3):

In your current situation I would advice to get device resolution that is most similar to your planned resolution or slightly bigger than it (800x600 -> 1024x720) and deal with it manually. Add black areas on sides or some artistic patterns that complement your game.

As already said GDI+ is not a common approach to 2D game nowadays, but the general principle of dealing with various screen aspects still stands.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice.  I'm pretty new to this.  What are some good books on XNA?  Probably a stupid question, but is XNA backwards compatible to Windows XP?

Comment: That question I can't answer here. I'm more of an OpenGL guy.

Comment: ... I should add that although I'm new to game programming, I'm not new to programming.  I did application development for 12 years.  So I wouldn't need a book that's too basic.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19141/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-started-with-xna