# Handling 3D perspective for different aspect ratio

Tags: opengl, 3d, mobile, aspect-ratio

I have problem for supporting different aspect ratio in developing Mobile Game.

I was developing on 2:3 screen which is iPhone 4 (Retina).

When I use width and height for screen size and use fixed FOV, then most of cases

look ok, but in 3:4 (which is iPad), the user can "See More" horizontally.

If I force the aspect ratio to 2:3, then looks "squeezed".

I am lost adjusting other values like moving camera, or changing FOV.

Is there any proper way or tips??

- Or, What is good FOV for portrait mobile device screen which can cover most of aspect ratio look ok? - I am currently using 45 - and force aspect ratio to 2:3

Comment: Welcome to the site. There are already several questions here which are related to yours, and which may provide insight. Consider http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19253/how-should-i-handle-different-aspect-ratios-in-a-fullscreen-game or http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/51134/handling-different-aspect-ratios-for-a-multiplayer-game for example. There are others if you search.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I already checked those comments but, it talks about 2D (which is "ortho" projection). I actually have problem in Perspective projection.

Comment: What are you currently doing?

Comment: The two basic solutions - either letterbox, or accept the necessity of different FOVs in different aspect ratios - are the same whether it's 2D or 3D.